# Django checkbutton for todo

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to Django, so please make it newbie friendly :D.
Its about a simple todo-list. I want every item to have three Buttons for deleting, editing or in this case checking.
In the following code I wanna create a check-button which sets a boolean value to True. But instand of doing anything the code is just refreshing the side. No error-messages or further information in the command.
So can you guys spot the mistake?

Glad for your help.

HTML:

```
                        <form method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button id="done" type="POST" action="{% url 'complete' do.id%}">
                                <i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
                            <button id="edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                            <button id="delete" action="#" method="POST"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                            <a href="/todo/{{do.id}}">{{do.task_title}}</a>
                        </form>
                    </li>
```

url:

```
    urlpatterns = [
        # match list,
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^add/$', views.addTodo, name='add'),

        url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/complete/$', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
..
]
```

view:

```
def completeTodo(request, todo_id):

    if request.method =='POST':
        print('alive')
        todo = Task.objects.get(pk=todo_id)
        todo.complete = True
        todo.save()

    return redirect('index')
```

Model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    task_explain = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('todo:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code says redirect to index when the view is done, which probably looks like a refresh in this case. However, you are not displaying any indication on its state of completion so nothing changes.
Either you can add `{{do.complete}}` somewhere or you can use the admin interface to see whether the `complete` variable has been set or not. [more info here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/) 
Do you know if the code in the view is run or not?